# convert values in a column consists of text map into integers and aggregate them

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as following:

```
data.frame("id" = 1:2, "tag" = c("a,b,c","a,d"))

 id       tag
  1       a,b,c
  2       a,d
```

in tag where ever is a or b consider as lan  and  and "d"="c"="con" means that a and b are consider as lan , d and c consider as con then we want to count the number of lan and con in each row in seperate columns like table in below:

I want to create two columns which are the aggregation of a,b,c to shows like the follows:

```
id  tag.  lan_count.   con_count
1  a,b,c    2            1
2    a,d    1            1
```

Could you please give me advice how to do this.

Comment: Please `dput` your input data.  What you have at the moment makes no sense to me.

Comment: I revised my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame("id" = 1:2, "tag" = c("a,b,c","a,d"))

df %>%
  separate_rows(tag, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  add_count(tag) %>%
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = tag, values_from = n) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(lan_count = sum(c_across(a:b), na.rm = TRUE), 
         con_count = sum(c_across(c:d), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-c(a:d))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Rowwise:  id
     id lan_count con_count
  <int>     <int>     <int>
1     1         2         1
2     2         1         1
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that your data is untidy.  So my solution is in two parts: first, [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) the data and then summarise it.  Once the data is tidy, the summary is trivial.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Adjust to suit your real data
maxCols <- 10
d <- data.frame(id = 1:2, tag = c("a,b,c","a,d"))
d %>% 
  separate(
    tag, 
    sep=",", 
    into=paste0("Element", 1:maxCols), 
    extra="drop", 
    fill="right", 
    remove=FALSE
  )  %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=starts_with("Element"), 
    values_to="Value", 
    names_prefix="Element"
  ) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  # Remove unused Values
  filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
  # At this point the data frame is tidy
  group_by(tag) %>%
  # Translate tags into  "categories".  Add more if required.  or write a function
  mutate(
    lan=Value %in% c("a", "b"),
    con=Value %in% c("c", "d")
  ) %>%
  # Adjust the column specification if more categories are added.  
  # Or use a factor instead of binary indicators
  summarise(across(lan:con, sum))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  tag     lan   con
* <fct> <int> <int>
1 a,b,c     2     1
2 a,d       1     1
```

Comment: Thanks this works well how can i add the id as well